# Cannot unload a feature because feature-file is nil?

Tags: feature

I'm trying to unload and reload a package (`realgud`) without restarting emacs.

To do this I'm trying to run:

```
(mapcar 'unload-feature (-filter (lambda (x) (string-match "gud" (symbol-name x))) features))
```

However, `unload-feature` does not seem to work if `feature-file` returns `nil` resulting in the following stack trace.

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument stringp nil)
  locate-file-internal(nil ("/Users/tomwright/.emacs.d/straight/build/test-simp..." "/Users/tomwright/.emacs.d/straight/build/loc-chang..." "/Users/tomwright/.emacs.d/straight/build/load-rela..." "/Users/tomwright/.emacs.d/straight/build/realgud" "/Users/tomwright/autopair" "/Users/tomwright/tools" "/Users/tomwright/test" "/Users/tomwright/extensions" "/Users/tomwright/completion" "/Users/tomwright/" "/Users/tomwright/autopair" "/Users/tomwright/tools" "/Users/tomwright/test" "/Users/tomwright/extensions" "/Users/tomwright/completion" "/Users/tomwright/" "/Users/tomwright/autopair" "/Users/tomwright/tools" "/Users/tomwright/test" "/Users/tomwright/extensions" "/Users/tomwright/completion" "/Users/tomwright/" "/Users/tomwright/autopair" "/Users/tomwright/tools" "/Users/tomwright/test" "/Users/tomwright/extensions" "/Users/tomwright/completion" "/Users/tomwright/" "/Users/tomwright/autopair" "/Users/tomwright/tools" "/Users/tomwright/test" "/Users/tomwright/extensions" "/Users/tomwright/completion" "/Users/tomwright/" "/Users/tomwright/autopair" "/Users/tomwright/tools" "/Users/tomwright/test" "/Users/tomwright/extensions" "/Users/tomwright/completion" "/Users/tomwright/" "/Users/tomwright/autopair" "/Users/tomwright/tools" "/Users/tomwright/test" "/Users/tomwright/extensions" "/Users/tomwright/completion" "/Users/tomwright/" "/Users/tomwright/autopair" "/Users/tomwright/tools" "/Users/tomwright/test" "/Users/tomwright/extensions" ...) (".so" ".so.gz" ".dylib" ".dylib.gz" ".elc" ".elc.gz" ".el" ".el.gz") nil)
  locate-file(nil ("/Users/tomwright/.emacs.d/straight/build/test-simp..." "/Users/tomwright/.emacs.d/straight/build/loc-chang..." "/Users/tomwright/.emacs.d/straight/build/load-rela..." "/Users/tomwright/.emacs.d/straight/build/realgud" "/Users/tomwright/autopair" "/Users/tomwright/tools" "/Users/tomwright/test" "/Users/tomwright/extensions" "/Users/tomwright/completion" "/Users/tomwright/" "/Users/tomwright/autopair" "/Users/tomwright/tools" "/Users/tomwright/test" "/Users/tomwright/extensions" "/Users/tomwright/completion" "/Users/tomwright/" "/Users/tomwright/autopair" "/Users/tomwright/tools" "/Users/tomwright/test" "/Users/tomwright/extensions" "/Users/tomwright/completion" "/Users/tomwright/" "/Users/tomwright/autopair" "/Users/tomwright/tools" "/Users/tomwright/test" "/Users/tomwright/extensions" "/Users/tomwright/completion" "/Users/tomwright/" "/Users/tomwright/autopair" "/Users/tomwright/tools" "/Users/tomwright/test" "/Users/tomwright/extensions" "/Users/tomwright/completion" "/Users/tomwright/" "/Users/tomwright/autopair" "/Users/tomwright/tools" "/Users/tomwright/test" "/Users/tomwright/extensions" "/Users/tomwright/completion" "/Users/tomwright/" "/Users/tomwright/autopair" "/Users/tomwright/tools" "/Users/tomwright/test" "/Users/tomwright/extensions" "/Users/tomwright/completion" "/Users/tomwright/" "/Users/tomwright/autopair" "/Users/tomwright/tools" "/Users/tomwright/test" "/Users/tomwright/extensions" ...) (".so" ".so.gz" ".dylib" ".dylib.gz" ".elc" ".elc.gz" ".el" ".el.gz"))
  file-loadhist-lookup(nil)
  file-provides(nil)
  file-dependents(nil)
  unload-feature(realgud-autoloads)
  eval((unload-feature 'realgud-autoloads) t)
  eval-expression((unload-feature 'realgud-autoloads) nil nil 127)
  funcall-interactively(eval-expression (unload-feature 'realgud-autoloads) nil nil 127)
  call-interactively(eval-expression nil nil)
  command-execute(eval-expression)
```

Is there a workaround for this or can I just ignore it? I've tried just ignoring the packages with no files like so:

```
 (-filter (lambda (x) (and (string-match "gud" (symbol-name x)) (feature-file x))) features)
```

Comment: Why is there no `realgud-autoloads` file? From which file did the feature come?

Comment: looks like `realgud-autoloads` is auto-generated. Not sure if it's actually putting a file on disk someplace, or if its fudging it.

Comment: It seemed to disappear when I unloaded other modules.